# how to load xml value into combo box

Tags: c#, xml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8V2A.jpg

so i have an XML file and wanted to display the name of the users into a combo box.
As i have another form for adding events, the user should select their name from the combo box to add an event to the data grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
```

`- <NewDataSet>`

`-<UserDetails>
<Name>Gabrile</Name>`

`<Email>gabrile@gmail.co.uk</Email>
<Contact-Number>03244613423</Contact-Number>
<Address1>10 gabriele street</Address1>`

```
<Address2>London</Address2>
```

`<Postcode>w12 0r4</Postcode>
</UserDetails>`

```
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: You can try usling XSLT for example

Comment: That's not valid xml. What are you expecting to happen if its not valid, what have you tried?

Comment: Use XDocument to load the file and use LINQ to query elements.

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image of text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your picture is just a fragment of the real XML file, something like this would work

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Load(filename);
foreach (var ud in d.Descendants("UserDetails"))
{
    string name = ud.Element("Name").Value;
    cb.Add(new ComboBoxItem() {
        Content = name
    });
}
```

where `cb` is your combobox.